# Proving independence of joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm trying to understand the proof of a condition for the independence of random variables, but I can't understand the step highlighted, any explanation would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with the phrase ["Without Loss of Generality"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality)?

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking why the equality of measures $P_{(X,Y)}=P_X\otimes P_Y$ can be inferred from the equality on sets of the form $(-\infty,x]\times (-\infty,y]$.

This is a consequence of the $\pi-\lambda$ theorem, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system#Application_to_probability_distributions).

Comment: Is there no simpler reasoning?